# VGA video driver for win 7 64bit - only available for 32bit 

Tags: windows-7, drivers, 64-bit, 32-bit, vga

I installed win7 64bit on a netbook, where initially win7 x32 was on, because i don't have a 32 bit system.

Now i have a problem, because there isn't a VGA driver on the Acer page (It's an **Acer Apsire One D255**).

I've found drivers for all the missing stuff in the internet on Acer's page and with Googling but not for the graphics...

I don't know which card it is in special. It's an on board card and i haven't found anything on everest...

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by you don't have a 32bit system?

Comment: i ment i have no win7 with 32bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a GMA 3150 graphics card by Intel (http://www.acer.co.uk/ac/en/GB/content/models/aspireoned255)

This [auto-detect option](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect/graphics) should help

Comment: yes it is a video-controller, but no more details but s/n. i found it also with everest. but both tools can't find a driver for it on their own

Answer (score 1):

[Driver for GMA 3150](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?lang=eng&DwnldID=18497)

Found this on intel web site and is for your graphics card for users utilizing intel Atom (as your laptop does.) with Win 7 64 bit.

There is a read me file on the site, suggest you give it the once over, choose your driver and download away.